# jQuery expand/collapse a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a MVC view that has a 3 columns table.  The table displays a list of Products.  Column #1 (product name) contains links to a product specific page.  When a user clicks on the links, I want to expand and display the product description and at the end of the product description, I want to include a link that takes the user to the product page.  If a user clicks on the link again, I want to collapse it back.  I have a model that represents the product and the product description is stored in its own field.

The table is built and populated as below.  Any insight on how to achieve the expand/collapse via jQuery is very much appreciated.

```html
<table id="products">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                foreach (product p in model.products)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to utilize product IDs as well. Add the specific product ID as a data attribute, then using jQuery, pull that attribute and reuse it to target rows containing the descriptions.

```js
$('.productname').on('click', function() {
      var id= $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.data' + id).slideToggle(500);
    });
```

```css
.hide  {display: none; }


/* -- below is just to "pretty up" the snippet ------ */


table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #aaa;}
th { background: #cef; color: #4cf; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 0.8em; padding: 3px;border: 1px solid #aaa;}
td { font-size: 1.1em; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-bottom: none; }
tr.collapsed td { padding: 0; border: none; }
.productname:hover, .active { background: #eff; }
.productdesc { padding: 5px 10px; background: #eff;  border-top: 1px solid #aaa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="products">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          
          <!-- 
               foreach (product p in model.products)
                {
-->
                    <tr class="productname" data-id="prodID00">
                      <!-- Change data-id="prodID00" to data-id="@p.productI‌D" -->
                      
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapsed">
                      <td colspan="3">
                        
                        <div class="hide productdesc dataprodID00">
                        <!-- Change class="hide productdesc dataprodID00" to class="hide productdesc data@p.productI‌D" -->
                          
                        <p>@p.productDescription <a href="#">@p.productLink</a></p></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
          
          <!-- } -->
          
          
          <!-- below are just manual iterations of the row above -->
          
                    <tr class="productname" data-id="prodID01">
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapsed">
                      <td colspan="3">
                        <div class="hide productdesc dataprodID01">
                        <p>product description and <a href="#">link</a></p></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr class="productname" data-id="prodID02">
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapsed">
                      <td colspan="3">
                        <div class="hide productdesc dataprodID02">
                        <p>product description and <a href="#">link</a></p></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr class="productname" data-id="prodID03">
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapsed">
                      <td colspan="3">
                        <div class="hide productdesc dataprodID03">
                        <p>product description and <a href="#">link</a></p></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr class="productname" data-id="prodID04">
                        <td>
                            @p.name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapsed">
                      <td colspan="3">
                        <div class="hide productdesc dataprodID04">
                        <p>product description and <a href="#">link</a></p></div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Note where the `prodID` is located in the rows.....

I removed the `foreach` function and brackets because it's invalid HTML. But if they are there and dynamically generate the HTML it'll work fine. The rows I used are just manual iterations opposed to dynamic iterations.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am getting the error `uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function` at the line `$('.productname').on('click', function() {`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Clearly things run fine in the snippet using jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: @degmo You would use.... `<div class="hide productdesc data@p.productID">` and above, in the table row preceding the product name you'd use `<tr class="productname" data-id="@p.productID">` You may need to concatenate the id into the html string properly. I merely inserted here so you could see the locations.

Comment: What this does is add the specific product id to the table row... then when that row is clicked, jQuery can find and show the specific description associated with that product ID. Without this specification either nothing slides open or all descriptions slide open in unison.

Comment: Scott, I found a jQuery load issue and took care of it to get past the error mentioned above. Now, nothing is happening when I click on the product names.  A couple of things: 1. I think it's because of this line `<div class="hide productdesc data @p.prodid">`.  It isn't matching the `data-id` attribute of the table row which is built as `<tr class="prodctname" data-id="@p.prodid"`. Would you be kind enough to explain to me what this line of code does?  I am new to front-end dev.  2.  I want product description to expand and display in the same `<td>` as product name.  How can I do that?

Comment: Hi scott, I got this to work but I have one slight modification I would like t make.  I want product description to expand and display within the same `<td>` as the product name.  How could I modify the code to do this?  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121203/discussion-between-degmo-and-scott).

Comment: Move the product description `div` inside that `td` and delete the extra table row. No offense, but you haven't even bothered to up vote this answer... not really inclined to write your script for you.

Comment: It's all working now and thanks for the help.  By the way, sorry for the delay in upvoting.  I had full intentions of doing it.